# How to solve exponential equation in python?

Tags: python, math, sympy, exponential, equation-solving

```py
from sympy import solve, symbols
from math import e

a = symbols('a')
r = solve(1604+14*a**(-1)-14x1604*(1-e**(-1604*a))**-1, a)
print(r)
```

When i try to solve this equation ,the programme seems keep running (for 4 hours) with no solution. anyone can help?

Comment: Shouldn't be an "*" between "14x1604"?

Comment: yes ,in pycharm i used '*' but the programme keep running with no solution

Answer (score 1):

Your equation

> 1604+14*a**(-1)-14*1604*(1-e**(-1604*a))**-1

seems to be insoluble. Why?

Because (1-e**(-1604*a))**-1.

You are raising 1-e to -1604*a, and this to -1.
If you omit the unknown there, like this:

```
r = solve(1604+14*x**(-1)-14*1604*(1-e**(-1604))**-1, x)
```

You get:

> 0.000671398427009400

And if you omit the multiplication and you put the unknown, like this:

```
r = solve(1604+14*x**(-1)-14*1604*(1-e**(x))**-1, x)
```

You get:

> No algorithms are implemented to solve equation 1604 - 22456/(1 -
> (54365636569181/20000000000000)**x) + 14/x

Maybe your equation HAS solution, so you can try to wait some time (maybe a long time) to check if your equation has solution and the solution is feasible (because it can be soluble but not feasible to calculate in a 'reasonable' time).